# Что делает tokenize из библиотеки razdel в python?

Tags: python

Пытаюсь разобраться с функцией tokenize в python.
Сразу скажу - я новичок.
Я уже и документацию прочел, и через print выводил результат.
Все равно не понимаю, что делает.

Comment: разбиение текста на токены. какие у вас сложности с этой функцией ?

Comment: Делит тест на отдельные элементы. Это не всегда просто. Где-то точка это конец предложения, а где-то это часть числа. Вот токенайзер и разбирается где что и делит соответственно.

Comment: @Интик, приведу пример. 
tokens = list(tokenize('привет, Андрей!'))
print(tokens)
Выводит следующее:
[Substring(0, 6, 'привет'), Substring(6, 7, ','), Substring(8, 14, 'Андрей'), Substring(14, 15, '!')]

Что означают цифры?

Comment: индекс. start index, stop index, text.

Answer (score 0):

Все, окончательно понял.

Как ответил @Интик "разбивает на токены". Я долго не мог понять, что за токены.
Потом понял, просто разбивает приложение на слова/символы (кроме символа пробела).
Стартовый индекс - это позиция с которой начинается слово, конечный индекс - которой заканчивается.
Например,
[Substring(0, 6, 'привет'), Substring(6, 7, ','), Substring(8, 14, 'Андрей'), Substring(14, 15, '!')]

0 - начальная позиция слова "привет". В слове привет 6 букв, т.е. 0+6 = 6 - это конечная позиция этого слова. И остальные слова/символы по аналогии.